# FAQ does not describe what is in or out of scope

Tags: discussion, scope

Unless I'm missing something, the FAQ does not explain what is in or out of scope.

When closing a technology-related question, a diamond mod said

> It is absolutely off-topic and you are invited to read through the FAQ
>   before posting next time.

I clicked on the FAQ link within "Questions on Japanese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to the Japanese language, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq)."

The only bits that I noticed describing what should or shouldn't be asked are:

> Japanese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for students,
>   teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the
>   Japanese language.

which is largely hype rather than meaningful information, and the section starting with

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face.

neither of which explain that technology-related questions are off-topic.

I'm not disputing that the consensus is that technology-related questions are treated as off-topic, I'm just saying it isn't documented in the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"FAQ" here was a shortcut for "the FAQ *and* relevant sections in Meta" (particularly [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)).

The FAQ you are referring to is a generic placeholder shared across all SE sites (and largely non-modifiable by JLU admins or users). It does however mention the existence of Meta and recommend users have a look there.

Said sections (as well as the original Area51 section, which for some reason does not get featured prominently, even though it contains an exhaustive list of good/bad sample questions) have explained time and again that JLU is not a site for resources about Japanese, nor language-unrelated cultural items about Japan.

There might be some grey area within Japanese-related questions, but there is absolutely none when it comes to "how do I do get my computer to do this"-questions...

I do not personally think this is the most user-friendly way to present the site rules (in a perfect world, some very dedicated users with a lot more spare time than I have, would organise FAQ-tagged posts into something much cleaner and more readable) and I realise it takes more effort than it should to find this information, but these are the breaks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this answer when I create a question and answer summarizing the situation - I hope I get around to it soon.

Comment: An answer that gets accepted by the community, that is!

Comment: Accepting because of the existence of [this question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage?lq=1) which is tagged FAQ.